# How to outline a circle on a grid?

Tags: c#

I want to outline my circle of cells, to do that I need a path that travels from each outer corner of the circle. Ive tried to illustrate it below.

Yellow is the circle, in red I've noted some coordinates the way I store them, and blue are where the path points would need to be:

[image]

To get the circle of cells surrounding cell at `gridX, gridZ` I use the following code:

```
public List<Cell> GetSurroundingCellsCircle(int gridX, int gridZ, int distance)
    {
        List<Cell> matches = new List<Cell>();
        int EX = distance + gridX;
        int EY = distance + gridZ;
        int SQ = distance * distance;

        for (int x = gridX - distance; x <= EX; x++)
        {
            for (int z = gridZ - distance; z <= EY; z++)
            {
                int c = x - gridX;
                int d = z - gridZ;

                if ((c * c + d * d) < SQ)
                {
                    Cell cell = GetCell(x, z);
                    if (cell != null)
                        matches.Add(cell);
                }
            }
        }

        return matches;
    }
```

So in this List I have access to all the cells in the circle. Now I need to find the border cells, then find the path of the outer corner of those cells. I do not really even know where to start.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007977/draw-circle-using-pixels-applied-in-an-image-with-for-loop

Comment: @Jonathan doesnt this just draw a full circle? I want to only draw the border. Im already drawinga  full circle

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you swap the x and y positions in your coordinate system? The standard is (x, y)...why change it to (y, x) and confuse people?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Well I didnt swap it to (y,x). Since its in 3d space my "y" is on the z-axis. therefore I use (x,z) since it was easier for me to understand. I do a lot of converting between grid position and world position, and it got confusing putting grid.y into a Vector3 z-axis. i.e new Vector3(grid.x, 0, grid.z)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the list of cells:

- For each column find the coordinates of the top cell (the one with the maximum Y coordinate). This gives you the cells at the top, so draw a line above each cell.
- For each row find the coordinates of the right-most cell (the one with the maximum X coordinate). This gives you the cells on the right side of the circle, so draw the line on the right of each cell.
- For each column find the coordinates of the bottom cell (the one with the minimum Y coordinate). This gives you the cells at the bottom of the circle, so draw the lines below each cell.
- For each row find the coordinates of the left-most cell (the one with the minimum X coordinate). This gives you the cells on the left side of the circle, so draw the lines on the left side of each cell.

This isn't the most efficient way of doing this, but if your grid isn't huge it should be quick enough.

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of brute force method I had in mind my self, I was hoping someone would have something more performant. But this is a good plan B! They do get quite big so :)

Comment: In that case I wouldn't use the GetSurroundingCellsCircle() function at all. Instead, I would use something like [Bresenham's circle drawing algorithm](https://iq.opengenus.org/bresenhams-circle-drawing-algorithm/) to get just the cells that are on the outline, and keep track of the next cell to know what lines to draw for the current cell.